# React useState, how to reset to initial value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a problem in this code. I need reset item array in line but don't work.

```
 if (!(element.name in filter){setItem([])}
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, cloneElement } from 'react';
import {fetchData} from '../helpers/fetchData';

function MainElement() {
   const [data, setData] = useState([]);
   const [filter, setFilter] = useState({});
   const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

  useEffect( () => {
    fetchData("http://localhost/cataleg/php/p3filtres.php")
      .then( category => {
        setData(category);
    });
  }, [])

  return (
    <div onChange={
      (e) => {
        const product = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
        [...product].map((element) => {
          if (!(element.name in filter){
            setItem([]);
          }else
          setItem([...item, element.value])
          return  filter[element.name]=item;
        })
      }
    }
    >
      {
          data && Object.entries(data).map((element,i) => {
            return (
              <div key={i}>
              <h3 key={element[0]}>{element[0]}</h3>
            {
            element[1].map(item => {
              return (
              Object.entries(item).map((value,i) => {
                if (i%2)
                return <div key={i}>
                          <input type="checkbox" key={value[1]} name={element[0]} value={value[1]}/>
                          <label key={`${value[1]}-${i}`} htmlFor={value[1]}>{value[1]}</label>
                       </div>
              })
            )
            })
            }
              </div>
            )
          })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default MainElement;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fK51.png)

When ckeckbox is checked I want to store in an object like:

```json
 {'processor': [I7,I5], 'RAM':['4GB','8GB']}
```

So I need reset item array for each key in the object. In may code item array is [I7,I5,'4GB','8GB']

Comment: I don't think `<div>` responds to `onChange`. Also inside your onChange call back, the 2nd line is missing a return.

Comment: You reset array but after it you call `setItem([...item, element.value])`, i think you must call it in `else` block

Answer (score 2):

There is a list of things worth fixing in your codes.

- `onChange` has no effect on `div`
- `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` should not be used inside a React component

  - Include the `<input>` checkboxes as part of your app
  - See [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) if you must reference other elements
- `.map` is being used like `.forEach`

  - `setItem([...item, element.value])` is called for every `element` regardless of your condition
  - `filtre` is misspelled
- `item` is derived state that should not have its own state

  - Use `data.filter` to compute `item`
  - See [Single Source of Truth](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lessons-learned)

Here is a minimal complete example you can run in your browser.

```js
function fetchProducts() {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000, [
      {"name": "carrot", type: "vegetable", quantity: 6 },
      {"name": "potato", type: "vegetable", quantity: 0 },
      {"name": "pretzels", type: "snack", quantity: 3 }
    ]))
}

function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([])
  const [isVegetable, veggieFilter] = useCheckbox(false)
  const [isStocked, stockFilter] = useCheckbox(false)
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    fetchProducts().then(setProducts).catch(console.error)
  }, [])
  function filter() {
    return products
      .filter(p => !isVegetable || p.type == "vegetable")
      .filter(p => !isStocked || p.quantity > 0)
  }
  return <div>
    Vegetable:{veggieFilter} In-Stock:{stockFilter}
    {filter().map(p => <pre>{JSON.stringify(p)}</pre>)}
  </div>
}

function useCheckbox(initValue = false) {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(initValue)
  return [
    checked,
    <input type="checkbox" checked={checked} onClick={_ => setChecked(!checked)} />
  ]
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I have edited and expanded my question